# Two Different Routes For One Action in ASP.Net Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying doing same action with different routes. For example;

" ../City/AddToCity/3 "

" ../City/AddToCity?infoId=3 "

should do same action on frontend. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following `Route` attribute to the action method:

```cs
[Route("/City/AddToCity/{infoId?}")]
public IActionResult AddToCity(int? infoId)
{
    .... your code
}
```

But if the `City` is your controller name, the `AddToCity` is the action method name and you have the following default route mapping in the `Startup.cs`

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

then you don't need to apply any additional routes. Just change the parameter name to `id`:

```cs
public IActionResult AddToCity(int? Id)
{
    .... your code
}
```

Comment: Can i use this for .cshtml buttons too or it’s just for Web API tests like using on Postman?

Comment: @XcellentEEE: Conventional routing typically used with controllers and views. Attribute routing used with REST APIs. Therefore, the attribute route defined above will work for the REST API as well. But MVC and REST API have completely different routing system, this is why conventional route defined above will work only with controllers and views.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[Route]` attribute.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CityController{

  [Route("addtocity/{id}" ,Name = "AddCity")]
  [Route("addtocity") Name = "AddCityWithInfoId"]
  public IActionResult AddtoCity(int? id = null, int? infoId = null)
  {
    .....
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i use this type for .cshtml buttons too or is it just for Web API? Anyway, i’ll try thanks.

Comment: yes you can use like `@Url.RouteUrl("AddCityWithInfoId",new {infoId = 4})`